# cannot load the oracle driver

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, javabeans

hey guys one more question 
following is the informations

tell me in comments if more info is needed

**INFO: Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@7471dc3d: defining beans [dataSource,studentJDBCTemplate]; root of factory hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'studentJDBCTemplate' defined in class path resource [pack1/config.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'dataSource' is required**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd ">
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
 <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"></property>
    <property name="password" value="trg"></property>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.23.3.132:1521:TRAIN"></property>
    <property name="username" value="trg12"></property>
    <!-- <property name="schema" value="TRAIN"></property> -->
 </bean>

 <bean id="studentJDBCTemplate" class="pack1.StudentJDBCTemplate"> 
 <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
 </bean>
```

this is a bean that i m using for database connection ...

Comment: make sure your OJDBC jar is in classpath

Comment: You need to add the JDBC driver JAR to the classpath.

Comment: @hoaz thanks guys i have include the jar file but now i m again getting the exception as mention above ..... prev excep is resolved this is the new one...   it says that datasource property required but i hav mentioned that property in my xml....

Comment: @Jesper thanks guys i have include the jar file but now i m again getting the exception as mention above ..... prev excep is resolved this is the new one...   it says that datasource property required but i hav mentioned that property in my xml....

Comment: Your subject is misleading as in your stack trace its not complaining about oracle driver.

Comment: @BhushanBhangale thanksss ... it was  silly mistake i am done ... thank youuu... i will delet this post...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the exception it seems your class pack1.StudentJDBCTemplate does not have dataSource property.

Are you sure the class extends JDBCTemplate or some other class which has dataSource property?